# Java Annotation Processor: only generate a source file if it does not exist

Tags: java

I am trying to write an annotation processor that generates source files, but will not overwrite source files that were generated during a previous run of the annotation processor.

Because I am just learning, I have created an annotation processor as described by Ryan Harter in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPlDL4EsY08.

I want to be able to generate a source file once, and then allow it to be edited manually by a developer without fear that the manual changes will be overwritten by subsequent runs of the annotation processor.  This may not be the norm, but I can think of several use cases where it would prove beneficial.

The specific piece of code within my AbstractProcessor subclass that I wish to modify is:

```
    try {
      JavaFile file = JavaFile
          .builder(builderType.packageName(), builder)
          .build();
      file.writeTo(filer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      messager.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR, "Failed to write file for element", el);
    }
```

Right now, it seems to me that all of the files in the generated source folder are getting deleted every time I run the build task for my gradle project. This means that any code I write in the annotation processor to check for the existence of a given generated source file will always return a negative result, even if the generated source file existed prior to running the build task.  Is there any way to prevent the generated source folder from getting scrubbed every time you rerun javac with an annotation processor? Or is there a better way to achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of an annotation processor is considered a product of compilation. Just like class files, these are [A] kept out of version control by default by all relevant systems, standards, and style guides, and [B] considered irrelevant, deletable chaff, in an aggressive fashion. Any `clean` command will delete these, they are overwritten with abandon, and tools may just decide to delete them for hard to discern reasons: They all are assumed to have the property that they don't contain anything important, they are merely a product of a process; a process that can be easily repeated.

For example, these files end up in `src/generated` or `generated_src`. Editing this file makes them not (entirely) generated, and that, in turn, means your codebase is now a lie: It has non-generated source files in a directory that strongly suggests they are generated.

Pain then ensues; pain that cannot be solved.

The solution is to not have these files in generated folders; they SHOULD be checked into version control, and they should NOT be considered trivially deletable chaff by tools (IDEs, build systems, etc). However, the annotation processor system does not *have* a baked in concept of such a directory.

The filer does let you get at the source file itself, so you could consider writing it out to there, that seems like the safest bet.

Note that other systems that work like yours are called 'skeleton' systems or 'scaffolding' systems: For example, [maven's archetype system](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html).

None of the many I know use annotation processors to do the job. You may simply be using the wrong toolchain.

Another solution is to import the custom code into a file that is then considered fully generated. For example, have the following rule:

1. You annotate something like so: `package com.foo; @DbModel class PersonTemplate {String name; LocalDate dateOfBirth;}`
2. The tool will then generate a source file containing `package com.foo; public class Person { public String getName() { ... }}` and a lot more boilerplate and DB query methods and more.
3. This file will have a comment generated at the top: `// Generated code. Don't edit this code; add methods to PersonExtras instead`
4. During your AP's compile run, you scan for a class named `com.foo.PersonExtras`. If it exists, you scan for static methods inside it. For every such method, you check if the first arg is `Person`. For example, `public void foo(Person p) {}`. If it is, you generate an instance method in `Person` that links to it: `public void foo() { PersonExtras.foo(p); }`. If it's not, you generate a static method in Person that links to it.

Your Person code is now an artefact of compilation and can be fully recreated at will by your AP with no user input, and yet it can be extended. The `PersonExtras` class can be placed in source control and is just in your usual src dir, and `Person.java` won't be in source control and can be deleted at will by tools.

In other words, 3 options:

1. Use the filer to find the source dir and generate your files there. This may not succeed and is a bit weird.
2. Don't write this product as an Annotation Processor, but as a stand-alone tool or plugin into an existing scaffolding generator system like maven's archetypes.
3. Solve the problem of having the produced classes be extensible in some other way, for example by using yet another class's fields and methods as a guide for how to generate the code: Thus ensuring that the source files your AP makes can remain 'intended to never be edited by human hands'.

Comment: With respect to option 1, how would one use the filer to get the source dir?

Comment: Use Filer's .getResource(StandardLocation.SOURCE_PATH) and find a source file you know must exist, then do some surgery on the path. There's a reason there is no .write() option for this location; you're not supposed to do this; options 2 and 3 are better.